# how to implement logging using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console in azure iotedge module? Display log in console as well as store in file also?

Tags: logging, azure-iot-edge

how to implement logging using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console in azure iotedge module? Display log in console as well as store in file also ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which errors did you get?

Comment: what do you mean "in file"? You are aware that files inside your modules (=containers) are not persisted unless you mount a drive into the container?! Also, logging to console does end up in the container logs. What else do you need?

Comment: Hi Silent, Want to implement Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console in azure iot edge module and show the log in visual studio console? please let me know that how to implement?